# Azure Graph API - Sign-in Logs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build Graph Rest API to list sign in audit based on this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

It seems like the filter clause for this API is not working.

I would like to filter all windows sign in for particular date and I've build below query.

auditLogs/signIns?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2020-04-28 and appDisplayName eq 'Windows Sign In'

It is always seems to return random number of records.

I'm able to donwload the audit sign in report from Azure portal and it always download the correct informaiton

Anyone experience any similar issues with filerting graph api?

Comment: Hi @Saz, Are you looking for windows sign-in details or Application sign-in?Because you are fetching for application sign-in in the above query.

Comment: I'm looking for windows sign-in details.  As per the doucmentation about link,GET tenant user sign-ins GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns.

Answer (score 0):

Below query gives auditlogs sign in for windows

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2020-04-28 and  startswith(deviceDetail/operatingSystem,'Windows')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is API issue or ADF issue. When I called the API only using the data parameter, I can see it is reading 96MB data but for some reason it is only writing 16 KB data in to the sink. I've created ADF issue - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/179

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the new `AzureADPreview` Module?

It comes with the cmdlet `Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs`